# Determining the physical host name / IP from the name of a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines

Is there any way to determine the host name or IP address of the physical host H given the name/IP address of a virtual machine running on H?

Thanks.

Comment: Which virtualisation tool?

Comment: Unknown - I have only the name/IP of the virtual machine and need to get the name/IP of the physical server using a third computer.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there is precisely one IP address and one host name?

Comment: Yes. In this case I do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial way to do so without using some sort of interface with the virtualisation tool. You may be able to figure this out by working deep, dark, black magic with the network, but it's unlikely you wouldn't already know the IP you seek if you had the authorization to cast these spells, and it's likely to be significantly more effort than it's worth to learn the proper incantations.

Answer (score 0):

Some virtualization tools stamp the hostname of the hypervisor in registry of the guest, but it is impossible to give a good answer without knowing the virtualization product used.